# Captions for Tikz drawings

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions

I have a question concerning captions for Tikz drawings. Below, you see the source code for a binary tree I've drawn with Tikz. I want to place a caption beneath it but unfortunately, the caption does not appear directly below the center of the tree but far at the right side of the tree.

Does anybody know how to place captions directly below of a tree?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=20mm, every node/.style={fill=red!60,circle, draw, inner sep=2pt},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm,nodes={fill=red!45}},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=20mm,nodes={fill=red!30}},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=10mm,nodes={fill=red!25}}]
\node {A}
   child {node {D}
         child {node {3}
              child {node {X}}
         child[missing]
         }
         child {node {9}}
      }
  child {node {V}
         child {node {19}}
         child {node {6}}
   };
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A tree}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

By the way, does anybody know how to place annotations/comments by the side of nodes such as in this picture (the Höhe tags): [image: http://s10.postimg.org/vjqvdsszt/Bildschirmfoto_2.png]

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You would want to center your tree using `\centering`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]  %% use position specifiers [htb]
\centering           %% <-- here
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=20mm, every node/.style={fill=red!60,circle, draw, inner sep=2pt},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm,nodes={fill=red!45}},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=20mm,nodes={fill=red!30}},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=10mm,nodes={fill=red!25}}]
\node {A}
   child {node {D}
         child {node {3}
              child {node {X}}
         child[missing]
         }
         child {node {9}}
      }
  child {node {V}
         child {node {19}}
         child {node {6}}
   };
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A tree}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add comment, an internal name () is required so that you can refer to later (in this demonstration (D) and (3) are defined). Here relative distance is used via `positioning` from tikzlibrary, meaning `pos=<0~1>, above, left, right, below, or combination of those keys` can be used to position the comments. Also, you need to use `draw=none` and `fill=none` since every node style is already defined with circle filled with color.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=20mm,  every node/.style={fill=red!60,circle, draw, inner sep=2pt},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=40mm,nodes={fill=red!45}},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=20mm,nodes={fill=red!30}},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=10mm,nodes={fill=red!25}}]
\node {A}
   child {node(D) {D}
         child {node(3) {3}
              child {node {X}}
         child[missing]
         }
         child {node {9}}
      }
  child {node {V}
         child {node {19}}
         child {node {6}}
   };
\draw (D) -- (3) node[below left= 0.5cm of D,draw=none,fill=none](){comment};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A tree}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```